# Adding values to coredata in swift share extension

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift2

I need to insert and fetch data from `coredata` in swift share extension. How can I do this

```
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController,NetworkSelectionViewControllerDelegate, PublishSelectionViewControllerDelegate,ApproverSelectionViewControllerDelegate{

    var selectedNetworkName = "Default"
    var selectedPublishName = "Select"
    var selectedApproverName = "Select"

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here



        return true
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean "share extension"? may be more code snippet could helpful.

Comment: Inserting and fetching in share extensions works just like it does in apps. Which part(s) do you need help with, specifically?

Comment: @TomHarrington i cannot call coredata function in share extension that we are created from application extension in project

Comment: @AntonyJacob What do you mean you "cannot call" Core Data? It's possible. What did you try and what happened when you did?

Comment: Did you found an answer to your problem?

Comment: @Ramis i didn't get the correct solution.