# Item is not recorded to CoreData from Share Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, ios8-share-extension

I did create **Share Extension**. Using this extension I am trying to insert new item to CoreData. The code is below. Variables *context* and *document* is created. *context.save()* not failing. Insertion to the CoreData using main/host app works fine and presented to UI.

Another thing what I noticed that all insertions from Share Extension are stored somewhere else, but not in the main app. It looks that these items are not merged to the main CoreData.

***Why my items insertion to CoreData throw Share Extension is not merged to main CoreData?***

```
let context = CoreDataStackManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext
let document = SGDocument(context: context)
document.name = "Document Name"
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
}
```

PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605036/adding-values-to-coredata-in-swift-share-extension) is similar question, but without answer.

Comment: Did you set up an app group so you can share data between the app and the extension?

Comment: Yes. My app and extension belongs to the same group.

Comment: Do the changes you make from the share extension appear in the main app after you kill and restart the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for it.

```
// In the extension I am setting that VC needs to be updated/refreshed.
UserDefaults.group.set(true, forKey: .udRefreshDocumentsVC)

// In the view controller adding listener for application will enter foreground.
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil, queue: nil, using: applicationWillEnterForeground)

// In the applicationWillEnterForeground method do reload.
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: Notification) {
        if UserDefaults.group.bool(forKey: .udRefreshDocumentsVC) {
            _fetchedResultsController = nil
            tableView.reloadData()
            UserDefaults.group.set(false, forKey: .udRefreshDocumentsVC)
        }
    }
```